# Can I search for whole strings in an NSSearchField/NSTextField (instead of only words)?

Tags: cocoa, macos, search, nssearchfield

Users must be able to search for whole strings, by typing only part of a string.
Example:
"this is" should match to "Could you tell me where this is?"
The matching strings should be available in the dropdown, and the text field should show the selected string from the dropdown. This does not work with autocompletion, because it will autocomplete *any* text with a found match.
I prefer to use an NSSearchField for this (because it clearly shows itself as a search facility) but it seems not to allow the search behaviour I want. What are my alternatives and how should I tackle it?